# kendo throws errors when building different themes

Tags: angular, sass, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

i'm having a problem with kendo and creating themes.

i have an angular app with scss, and i if tell kendo to change color of something like this

```
    ...other stuff
    $accent: purple;
    @import "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/all.scss";
    ...other stuff
```

it works flawlessly! all good!

but now i want to build two themes so that i can swap between them, like so

```
    ...other stuff
   :root {
       $accent: purple;
       @import "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/all.scss";
    }

   .other-theme{
       $accent: yellow;
       @import "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/all.scss";
    }
    ...other stuff
```

but it doesn't work. the error that is getting thrown at compilation is

```
   CssSyntaxError [path of the scss] can't resolve ') format("truetype")' in [other path]


       font-style: normal;
       font-weight: normal;
       src: url(#{$icon-font-url} format("truetype"));
```

why changing a color affects the font? i'm not touching it in any way, i'm going crazy trying to build a theme like this.

thanks to everyone that will help :D

Answer (score 0):

I happen to work on the kendo themes and a customer pointed me to this thread, because he had the same issue.

To get the simplest thing out of the door -- it's not the color change that's causing the issue. It's how variables are treated when nested inside classes.

To go into details, we convert non text files (images, fonts) to base64 encoded string and append them in an aptly named variable called `$data-uris`. Later, we retrieve the content by key.

When you are using the theme as is, everything is fine and the variable is found.

However when you nest the import things get a bit strange, for a lack of a better word. I am not sure for the exact reason "why" but in this nested import scenario, when we try to append said encoded content it's not appended in the same location where we try to retrieve it from.

Good news is that this all can be workaround relatively easy: we just need to reset one variable before each such import. Resetting the variable will make it globally available.

Also, because there is not true "import once" or something similar in sass and because we've optimized for one theme per file, we do a bit of trickery to ensure content is loaded once and only once. It's a very rudimentary caching where we cache modules by keys. So you need to modify another variable.

Both things combined:

```
$imported-modules: (); // reset the list of loaded modules for good measure
$data-uris: (); // reset the data-uris thus making them globally availble

.dark-theme {
    @import "all.scss";
}


$imported-modules: ();
$data-uris: ();

.light-theme {
    @import "all.scss";
}
```

Update:
there might be an additional issue regarding nesting. You can follow: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-themes/issues/2286. I will try to resolve that issue in a reasonable timeframe.